# How to get rid of large left and right margins in chart.js donut chart?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, chart.js, donut-chart

I'm struggling with left & right margins on a donut chart I have created using [Chart.js](http://www.shilling.co.uk/survey/Charts/docs/). More specifically, it seems impossible to reduce the seemingly 25% side margins on the donut charts. Does anyone know how I accomplish this or if it's even possible? I've been looking over all the github issues and documentation I can find, but it seems like nothing is working.

Github Issues I've found:

- [Issue-449](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/449)
- [Issue-1266](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1266)

Currently this is what I have

[image]

The issue is the large margins on the sides, I can't get them to go away no matter what properties I adjust

[image]

Dimension-wise I'd like both charts to take up 50% of the blue container's width and 75% of its height. I'm trying to use percentages for everything so it's responsive. If I use the responsive property in the chart.js config it keeps those side margins in tact. Ultimately, this is what I am trying to do roughly (the desired height isn't accurate in this example).

[image]

Right now I'm generating the charts like so

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

Chart.pluginService.register({
        afterUpdate: function (chart) {
            if (chart.config.options.elements.center) {
                var helpers = Chart.helpers;
                var centerConfig = chart.config.options.elements.center;
                var globalConfig = Chart.defaults.global;
                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

                var fontStyle = helpers.getValueOrDefault(centerConfig.fontStyle, globalConfig.defaultFontStyle);
                var fontFamily = helpers.getValueOrDefault(centerConfig.fontFamily, globalConfig.defaultFontFamily);

                if (centerConfig.fontSize)
                    var fontSize = centerConfig.fontSize;
                // figure out the best font size, if one is not specified
                else {
                    ctx.save();
                    var fontSize = helpers.getValueOrDefault(centerConfig.minFontSize, 1);
                    var maxFontSize = helpers.getValueOrDefault(centerConfig.maxFontSize, 256);
                    var maxText = helpers.getValueOrDefault(centerConfig.maxText, centerConfig.text);

                    do {
                        ctx.font = helpers.fontString(fontSize, fontStyle, fontFamily);
                        var textWidth = ctx.measureText(maxText).width;

                        // check if it fits, is within configured limits and that we are not simply toggling back and forth
                        if (textWidth < chart.innerRadius * 2 && fontSize < maxFontSize)
                            fontSize += 1;
                        else {
                            // reverse last step
                            fontSize -= 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (true)
                    ctx.restore();
                }

                // save properties
                chart.center = {
                    font: helpers.fontString(fontSize, fontStyle, fontFamily),
                    fillStyle: helpers.getValueOrDefault(centerConfig.fontColor, globalConfig.defaultFontColor)
                };
            }
        },
        afterDraw: function (chart) {
            if (chart.center) {
                var centerConfig = chart.config.options.elements.center;
                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

                ctx.save();
                ctx.font = chart.center.font;
                ctx.fillStyle = chart.center.fillStyle;
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                var centerX = (chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2;
                var centerY = (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2;
                ctx.fillText(centerConfig.text, centerX, centerY);
                ctx.restore();
            }
        },
})

        var config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: [
                  "Savings",
                  "Checking"
                ],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [300, 50],
                    backgroundColor: [
                      "#FF6384",
                      "#36A2EB"
                    ],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                      "#FF6384",
                      "#36A2EB"
                    ]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive:false,
                maintainAspectRatio:false,
                title: {
                    fullWidth: false,
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Current Balance'
                },
                legend: {
                    position:'bottom',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth:15
                    }
                },
                elements: {
                    center: {
                        // the longest text that could appear in the center
                        maxText: '$000000',
                        text: '$40,000',
                        fontColor: 'black',
                        fontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
                        fontStyle: 'normal',
                        minFontSize: 1,
                        maxFontSize: 256,
                    }
                }
            }
        };


        var ctx = document.getElementById("myDoughnutChart").getContext("2d");
        var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("myDoughnutChart2").getContext("2d");
        var myDoughnutChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, config);
};
</script>

</head>
```

With the portion of the HTML looking like this

```
<div class="col left">
    <div class="section side-sm" style="background-color:blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="section side-sm" style="background-color:black;">
    </div>
    <div class="section side-lg">
        <div class="accountContainer" style="height:75%;overflow:hidden;">
            <canvas id="myDoughnutChart" style="background-color:white;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="expenseContainer" style="height:75%;overflow:hidden;">
            <canvas id="myDoughnutChart2" style="background-color:white;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the applicable CSS for that HTML looking like this

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/* Start: Column-Specific */
.col {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

.left, .right {
    width:25%;
    height:97%;
    background-color:white;
}
/*Start: Section-Specific */
.section {
    width:100%;
    clear: both;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display:table;
}

.col.left>.section, .col.right>.section {
    width:97%;
}
.side-lg {
    height:40%;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-top:1%;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get rid of those large margins and accomplish the look that I've described/shown? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I misread your question, I thought you need google charts. Anyway, there is potential solution for chart js. You will need to add `width` and `height` attributes. For example:

```
<canvas id="myDoughnutChart" width="250%" height="310%"></canvas>
```

Here is a link to JsFiddle with your code + updated `width` and `height` attributes for the first chart (second one is the same for comparison):
https://jsfiddle.net/cncdf4od/2/

Comment: Huh, I guess I got thrown off by the fact that the docs say that margins are all 0 by default, so I never thought to include it. That did the trick though, thanks! EDIT: Nevermind, that didn't actually work. it didn't change anything :(

Comment: It has to be something with the Chart.js library, since I see that your jsfiddle is using the google chart library.

Comment: Thanks for the update! That works perfectly to get rid of the left and right margins, but how can I get both of the charts side-by-side? So, basically how can I get each chart to only take up 50% of the width of that blue div? It's ok if the height isn't 75%, I'm more concerned with the half and half width.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you mean, but you can adjust positions with CSS. Problem is that blue area is not wide enough, and you will have to update canvas widths on blue area width change. Anyway here is one example: https://jsfiddle.net/cncdf4od/4/

Comment: No worries, I figured it out. I just needed to remove the 75% height and set the width at 50% and play around with a few other dimensions. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I'm glad if it helped a bit. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm going to post another question in a few about how to add arced text inside the wedges because so far I haven't found any sources showing how to do that. I've just found sources that show how to place text in the wedge, but not curve it to fit the wedge.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I will be on a road soon, but I'd like to see the answer to that one. Even though I suppose it would be hard to find native way, so  maybe some CSS overlay or something. I will check it when I have more time.

Comment: Ok, I'll link to it here once I create it.

Answer (score 5):

there is actually a simple solution i found in one of the issues
aspectRatio: 1 in the chart options

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/449